# Run Qt applications as Wayland clients

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, wayland, qtwayland

I want to run a basic qt application using wayland.

Before i ask for help, will share the steps that i performed.

**Step 1:**

Got wayland 1.11.0 downloaded and installed. (https://wayland.freedesktop.org/releases.html)

**Step 2:**

Weston also installed and running (weston-1.3.0.tar.xz)

**Step 3:**

Downloaded the Qtwayland from github (https://github.com/qt/qtwayland/tree/5.7.0)

when i try building it.. it still says "Project WARNING: QtWayland requires Wayland 1.6.0 or higher, QtWayland will not be built"

but you can see my output from wayland-scanner-v below

```
qtwayland-5.7$ ../wayland-1.11.0/wayland-scanner -v
wayland-scanner 1.11
```

NOTE: I obvious have qtcreate on my ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Thank you.

Comment: Looking at the `qtwayland.pro` build file, it seems to use `pkg-config` to locate the Wayland scanner executable. Did the build of Wayland you did install any `pkg-config` files globally? If you do something like `pkg-config --cflags wayland-scanner`, does this return anything? The `qmake` build tool just might not be able to find the actual Wayland library.

Comment: when i do pkg-config --cflags wayland-scanner, it does not return anything... :\ and the qtwayland.pro is kinda  normal...

Comment: I'm not sure if `wayland-scanner` is the best thing to be searching for, that was a suggestion. If you do `pkg-config --list-all`, and don't see anything related to Wayland, then I would run `make install` on the Wayland build you did. It just seems like `qmake` doesn't know where those headers and libraries are, because `pkg-config` doesn't know where they are. So you need to put them somewhere it can find them, which `make install` should do. An alternative is to add their location to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.